# CMake not finding boost libraries from conan

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, conan

So I'm trying to get my cmake to work with conan/boost. For this I have a simple conan file:

```
from conans import ConanFile

class Boost_Conan_Cmake_MinimalConfig(ConanFile):

    name = "Boost_Conan_Cmake_MinimalConfig"
    generators = "cmake"
    options = {"shared": [True, False], "st": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False, "st": True}

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires("boost/1.69.0@_/_")
    self.options["boost"].shared = False
```

I call this via `conan install . --build=missing`. This runs perfectly fine and installs boost without problems. When investigating into the folder you can also find all the boost libraries etc.
Next comes my CMakeList.txt. It's pretty straight forward:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

# CHANGE PROJECT NAME, SOURCES AND DEPENDANT TARGETS
project(boost-conan CXX)
include(conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

set(TARGET_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(${TARGET_NAME}_SRC src/main.cpp)

find_package(Boost 1.69.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)

add_executable(test "src/main.cpp")
target_include_directories(test PUBLIC $(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS))
target_link_libraries(test Boost::filesystem)
```

However, when I try to run this CMake file I get an error:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19041.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.26.28805.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 
Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual 
Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Conan: Adjusting output directories
-- Conan: Using cmake global configuration
-- Conan: Adjusting default RPATHs Conan policies
-- Conan: Adjusting language standard
-- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: D:/boost-conan
-- WARN: CONAN_COMPILER variable not set, please make sure yourself that your compiler and version 
matches your declared settings
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake- 
3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: filesystem) (found suitable version
  "1.69.0", minimum required is "1.69.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2179 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/boost-conan/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Or does anyone have an idea why this error occurs? The Error message alone doesn't really help...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run cmake with `Boost_DEBUG` option set to `ON` (from command line it is `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`). That way CMake will print which exact Boost libraries are searched and where (directories). Compare actual files in these directories with ones searched by CMake.

Comment: From the error message: "ould NOT find Boost (missing: filesystem) (found suitable version  "1.69.0", minimum required is "1.69.0")". So, have you checked whether Boost filesystem library is present (installed / build)?