# Boost with conan + CMake not found

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, conan

I tried to use conan to integrate boost into my cpp Projekt.
While it seems conan does install the boost libraries, CMake says

> -- Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.78.0")

For the basic setup I tried to follow: https://codetrips.com/2020/03/20/1198/

And I found the question [CMake not finding boost libraries from conan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66779739/cmake-not-finding-boost-libraries-from-conan), but since the setup seems to be a bit different (and no solution was found), I would like to present my problem and project.

My project layout is:

```
    - ${project_root}/CMakeLists.txt
    - ${project_root}/conanfile.txt
    - ${project_root}/main.cpp
    - ${project_root}/build
```

With CMakeLists.txt:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
    project(boost_process_test)

    include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
    find_package(Boost 1.78.0)
    
    add_executable(test main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE Boost)
```

and with conanfile.txt

```
    [requires]
    boost/1.78.0

    [generators]
    cmake
```

and with main.cpp

```
    #include <boost/process.hpp>
    
    int main() {
        return 0;
    }
```

Within the build directory I called

> $ conan install ..

yielding the output:

> Configuration:
>  [settings]
>  ...
>  build_type=Release
>  ...
>  boost/1.78.0 from 'conancenter' - Cache

When calling

> $ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..

the above stated output is yielded.

Comment: It seems you forgot to call `conan_basic_setup()`. Also, call to `cmake_minimum_required` should prepend to `project` and all other commands. And `add_executable(test ...)` should prepend to `target_link_libraries(test ..)` (a target should be created before one is able to link it with the libraries).

Comment: Would you mind formulate your comment as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: I treat incorrect copying code from the guide as a **typo** sort of problem. It is true that everyone does a typo, but that doesn't mean that such problems should be included into Question/Answer "book", which Stack Overflow is. You have the problem resolved, which is nice. Just forget about it and move on.